# sass with grunt is not working

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I have been trying to setup a grunt task to compile my sass files but nothing seems to be working.

My working structure is

```
  Gruntfile.js
  package.json
  assets
  |
  |--sass
  |  |
  |  styles.scss
  |
  |--css
```

and this is my grunt file

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded'
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/sass',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '../css',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
};
```

I have already verified that I have sass installed

when I run `grunt sass`, it says that everything when okay. But I have yet to see a compiled css file. The only way that I got this to work is by using the `"destination" : "source"` syntax.

*EDIT*: The exact problem I'm having is not that the files are generating in the wrong place, but that they aren't generating. Also, grunt is not showing any errors

Does anyone have a clue as to what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This configuration works for me:

```
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'assets/sass',
    src: ['**/*.scss'],
    dest: 'assets/css',
    ext: '.css'
}]
```

Perhaps the `../` is throwing it off; I don't believe the destination path is relative to the source path, it's relative to the Gruntfile.

Comment: not sure if my system wasn't working or maybe the files weren't being generating when are I thought they should have been, giving it the effect of not working or what, but your code made it work. Thanks

Comment: What does the 'cwd' stand for? Current working directory? Changing the cwd to what you suggested fixed my issue.

Comment: It could be a bug, i did the same. changing my `files:` to what @Ben suggested, and then revert everything back to what i had before. Everything works file.

Comment: In my case it was the trailing `/` for some reason. Taking it off the end made it work. Seems kinda strange tho.